# Julia - Change method definition within a function

Tags: function, methods, julia

So here's what I want, I have a function: `f(x,t)=...` where `x` is the "true" variable and `t` is a parameter. However, I need to use this function as a parameter in the Calculus package's `derivative`. This function requires a function with only one parameter. For this what I thought off was to redefine a method `f(x)=f(x,t)` where I fix the `t` parameter before passing it to the `derivative` function. **This has to be done within another function.**

However, doing this literally returns this error :

`syntax: cannot add method to function argument f`

Comment: use a lambda:    `f2 = x -> f1(x,5)`

Comment: You can use [anonymous functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/functions/#man-anonymous-functions-1) for this purpose (too late :D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe due to variable scope issues you should simply select a different name for your new function. You can also use anonymous functions instead of named definitions.

```
function foo(t_val) 
  newf(x) = f(x, t_val) 
  derivative(newf, otherparams...) 
end
```

With anonymous functions,

```
function foo(t_val)
    derivative(x -> f(x, t_val), otherparams...) 
end
```

You can also assign anonymous functions to variables and use the variables as a function.

```
function foo(t_val) 
    newf = x -> f(x, t_val) 
    derivative(newf, otherparams...) 
end
```